# Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell... Sending command `exec ssh -e none bin'

Tags: tramp, spacemacs, ssh

Tramp hangs for several minutes every time I launch Emacs, giving me these errors:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for bin using scp...
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh  -e none bin'
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
Timeout reached, see buffer `*tramp/scp bin*' for details
Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
Tramp: Opening connection for bin using scp...failed
```

My tramp debug:
https://gist.github.com/2dc7672fb5aa22f06b53

I believe it's related to this:
https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/1000

and this: 
https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/3422#issuecomment-148919047

I followed [the directions from the Spacemacs FAQ](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/FAQ.org#why-is-spacemacs-hanging-on-startup), which suggests this solution:

`(setq tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options
   "-o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%%C' -o ControlPersist=no")`

This didn't have any effect.

I also tried this:

`(setq tramp-ssh-controlmaster-options nil)`

...but I got the same result.

The FAQ suggests that if the above doesn't work, you can try to put these settings directly in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *  
ControlMaster auto  
ControlPath ~/.ssh/master -%r@%h:%p  
ControlPersist = no `
```

So I did this, which caused the error message to change to this:

```
Tramp failed to connect.
Garbage at the end of the line. -%r@%h:%p  
If this happens repeatedly, try M-x tramp-cleanup-this-connection
```

I did also try `tramp-cleanup-this-connection` also, but it too had no effect.

How can I get Emacs to stop hanging on startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message `Sending command 'exec ssh  -e none bin'` is a clue that an error is occurring when `exec-path-from-shell` reads the path from the shell environment.

Once I figured this out, I checked my `.bashrc` and found the offending line:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting`

Killing this line solved the Emacs launch problem.