# Tramp connection fails with "timeout reached"

Tags: tramp, ssh

I've been using `tramp` to edit remote files for a few years now, but suddenly it stopped working yesterday. I haven't changed anything relevant that I can think of. For testing, I tried opening a file on `localhost` with `\C-x C-f /ssh:localhost:/home/terdon/test`. That bring up the `Waiting for prompts from remote shell...` message and times out after about a minute with:

```
Timeout reached, see buffer '*tramp/ssh localhost*' for details
```

The `*tramp/ssh localhost*` is shown in the buffers menu but disappears as soon as I try to switch to it.

**Details**

- I am running GNU emacs 25.3.1 on Arch Linux.
- I have updated my system and the elpa packages I have installed.
- To rule out problems with the remote prompt, I have replaced my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` with:

  ```
  $ cat ~/.bashrc
  PS1='$ '
  $ cat ~/.profile
  PS1='$ '
  ```

  Yes, my default shell is bash and no, I don't have a `~/.bash_profile`.
- I have set up passwordless ssh to all the servers that I've tried and which used to work. Including `localhost` (`ssh localhost` works fine with no password).
- My `.emacs` file has (the full file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/QGgPE3SS):

  ```
  (setq tramp-default-method "sshx")
  (setq tramp-verbose 10)
  ```
- The contents of the `*debug tramp/ssh localhost*` buffer are here: https://pastebin.com/F6r6d5cN.
- I read [Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell... Sending command `exec ssh -e none bin'](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/20802/241) and added these lines to my `~/.ssh/config` file:

  ```
  Host *
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPersist = no
  ```

  However, despite that, as you can see in the output in the previous bullet point, I still get `command-line line 0: Missing ControlPersist argument` line. Is that an issue?
- Running the `ssh` command from tramp's log maually works fine:

  ```
  $ ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none localhost
  Last login: Tue Apr 24 13:58:15 2018 from ::1
  $
  ```
- Trying the same thing after loading emacs with `emacs -Q` gives the same problem, so it isn't something to do with my `~/.emacs`.
- I created a new user with default settings and tried as that user and it worked! So while `emacs -Q` doesn't solve the issue, **running as a new user does!** What could cause that?

What else can I check? How can I get my tramp back again?

Comment: You have set `tramp-verbose` to 10, so there is a Tramp debug buffer. Pls show it.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus I link to it in my penultimate bullet point: https://pastebin.com/F6r6d5cN (sorry, I guess it got lost in the noise, I was trying to give as much detail as I could).

Comment: According to the traces, Tramp sends the command "`exec ssh   -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath='tramp.%C' -o ControlPersist=no -e none localhost`". Afterwards, it waits 1 minute for output, but nothing happens. Could you try the command from a shell, and see what happens?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus that works immediately. I log into `localhost` after ~1sec or less.

Comment: Strange. Have you tried to use Tramp with a clean Emacs, after calling `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus argh, should have thought of that, thanks. Anyway, I just tried it and got the same issue. Weird. Even weirder, however, I tried creating a new user and then opened a file as that user and it worked! What can cause that? `emacs -Q` still failing and yet a new user with a default configuration working?

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus thank you very much for your help. I finally tracked the problem down: it was a malformed line in `~/.inputrc`. Removing that line fixed the problem. Now why the local `.inputrc` would affect opening a remote shell (when connecting to an actual remote machine, not `localhost`, of course), I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was a malformed `~/.inputrc` file. I had been playing around with it while trying to answer a question over at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and had left this line:

```
Control-J: "$(date)"
```

Removing that line fixed my problem with `tramp`. I don't understand why the local `~/.inputrc` would affect my remote shell (I also faced this problem when connecting to actual remote hosts, not only `localhost`), but apparently it did.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue mentioned in the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc11):

> If you have Control-j mapped in your ~/.inputrc ... it can cause tramp to never finish recognizing the shell prompt.

For me, the problem went away when I conditionally defined C-j binding only for non-dumb terminals:

```
$if term=dumb
# skip
$else
Control-j: foo
$endif
```